# How can I enable player names in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Kindle Fire, and I connect on WiFi with my friends who have iPods. When we are connected, they can see my player name above my head, but I can't see theirs.  Why does this happen?  How can I fix it by enabling the names?

Comment: I didn't think you see the player names on a Findle Fire.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you changed any settings, but there is a setting that disables player names, can't say that that is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the video section in settings, scroll down then you will find "Show in-game names". Just turn it on!

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're on different devices.

When I connect with my sister, we can both see each other's names and she's on a Samsung so it might not be that.